# Logistic Regression from Scratch, Cost is not decreasing

Tags: regression, classification, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform Logistic Regression from scratch, but the cost is not decreasing. The cost function array is

J_all = [0.6931471785599453,
0.7013523852395079,
1.0799382321159159,
1.4184962890456663,
1.2090967630312366,
1.3564457452734269,
1.2571265595127734,
1.2870719263130037,
1.306411844446772,
1.229356753355045,
1.3446092043800832,
1.1813483789340946,
1.372813359239384,
1.1431300497707213,
1.391357334040078,
1.1143844952172193,
1.4016419750913938, ...].

As you can see cost function is not decreasing.

Below is my code. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
def logistic_regression(X, Y, iterations, learning_rate):

X = X.to_numpy()
Y = Y.to_numpy()

m = X.shape[0]
n = X.shape[1]

print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)

print(m, n, sep = " ")

W = np.zeros(n)
B = 0

print(W.shape)

J_all = []

for i in range(iterations):
    print(W)
    print(B)
    Z = (np.dot(X, W)) + B

    print(Z.shape)

    F = sigmoid(Z)

    print(F.shape)
    
    print(Z)
    print(F)
    
    epsilon = 1e-9  # Small epsilon value to avoid division by zero

    E = np.sum(Y * np.log(F + epsilon) + (1 - Y) * np.log(1 - F + epsilon))

    print(E)

    J = (-(1/m)) * E

    print(J)

    DW = np.dot(X.T, (F - Y))
    DB = (F - Y)

    W = W - (learning_rate/m) * (DW)
    B = B - (learning_rate/m) * np.sum(DB)

    J_all.append(J)

return J_all, W, B
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found the solution. The code I provided is right; the solution was just to decrease the learning rate from 0.005 to 0.001, which did the magic.